# In Canada do I need an Advanced license to use a DVAP?

Tags: legal, canada, d-star

In Canada do I need an Advanced license to use a D-Star DVAP hotspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DVAP hotspot uses (or at least can be configured to use) simplex operation. This means that both your radio and the DVAP hotspot use the same frequency to transmit and receive. If you are operating with the DVAP in simplex mode, it does not count as a repeater and so **an Advanced Qualification is not necessary.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is what I had worked out in my head but just wanted to double check. Thanks